# calculate difference between two interpolated grids using python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy.spatial, scipy

I'm trying to calculate difference between two interpolated grids. The grids are of different shapes, so cannot use np.subtract to calculate the difference. Any help on how to calculate the difference?

```
#create two interpolated grids from two set of xyz points and calculate difference  
ixx = np.array(self.ix)
iyy = np.array(self.iy)
izz = np.array(self.iz)

iminx = min(ixx.flat)
imaxx = max(ixx.flat)
iminy = min(iyy.flat)
imaxy = max(iyy.flat)

# post surface - get extents
pxx = np.array(self.px)
pyy = np.array(self.py)
pzz = np.array(self.pz)

pminx = min(pxx.flat)
pmaxx = max(pxx.flat)
pminy = min(pyy.flat)
pmaxy = max(pyy.flat)

ixi = np.arange(iminx, imaxx, self.cellsize)
iyi = np.arange(iminy, imaxy, self.cellsize)
iX,iY = np.meshgrid(ixi,iyi)
iextent = (min(ixi), max(ixi), min(iyi), max(iyi))

pxi = np.arange(pminx, pmaxx, self.cellsize)
pyi = np.arange(pminy, pmaxy, self.cellsize)
pX,pY = np.meshgrid(pxi,pyi)
pextent = (min(pxi), max(pxi), min(pyi), max(pyi))

igrid = griddata((ixx, iyy), izz, (iX, iY), method='linear')
pgrid = griddata((pxx, pyy), pzz, (pX, pY), method='linear')    


# would like to calculate difference, but this won't work, due to different shapes
changegrid = np.subtract(pgrid, igrid)
```

igrid shape is (181, 130)
pgrid shape is (184, 126)

Another important information is these are spatial grids with overlapping spatial extents. If we just broadcast/extend array shapes, would that be enough? I do not want to subtract the grids at wrong x/y locations. So basically like in GIS/Arcmap how we calculate raster difference at each cell at a particular xy cell location.

I'm not sure why this question is under hold and not considered as GIS. The grids are spatial grids with extent falling under GIS coordinate system.

Comment: What are the dimensions of `pgrid`and `igrid` ( `pgrid.shape` and  `iigrid.shape`) ?

Comment: have a look at [Subtracting numpy arrays of different shape efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33677183/subtracting-numpy-arrays-of-different-shape-efficiently)